# In controller i used input tag which will check if "0" then unchecked else checked. I am having escaping problem

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a checkbox in my form:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" 
         onclick="active1(this)" id='.$row->id.' data-id='.$row->id.' '.$row->is_show.'   '.  "checked". '  >
```

I am expecting code like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="activeMenuItemEntry(this)"
id={{$row->id}} data-id="{{$row->id}}" {{ $row->is_active ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

I am confused how can i write this part `{{ $row->is_active ? 'checked' : '' }}`

Comment: what error you are getting by running above code ?

Comment: You'll want to make sure you're outputting quotes around the HTML attributes `id` and `data-id` the same way you have them around `class`, `type`, and `onclick`.

Comment: `$row->is_active` value is 0 or 1 and this is not checking the value it is always checked.

Comment: I just need to check the condition `?` and ` :' ' ` if this works my code will run